# SQLite3.Python.Проверка значения в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Что делает моя функция: передаёт значение `coins` из одной строки, в другую, то есть вычитает монетки у одного и даёт другому, переводит деньги одного другому.
Как это выглядит:

```
def givem(p1,p2,p3):
con = sqlite3.connect('accs.db')

cur = con.cursor()

id1 = p1
id2 = p2
pay = p3
sql = """
UPDATE persons 
SET coins = coins - ?   
WHERE id =?
"""
cur.execute(sql, [(pay),(id1)]) #вфигачиваем через запятую сначала инфу про кол-во монет  и id

sql = """
UPDATE persons 
SET coins = coins + ?   
WHERE id =?
"""

cur.execute(sql, [(pay),(id2)])

con.commit()
cur.close()
```

В чём беда: если у первого на счету нет монет или недостаточно то перевод всё равно совершится, у второго будут монеты, а у первого счёт пойдёт в минус

Задача: Добавить в начало проверку сравнивающую `pay`(кол-во денег которые хотят перевести) и кол-во которое на данный момент у человека1 и в случае, если монеток меньше выводить `print()` ну или ошибку.

Попытка реализации:  В эту же функцию я попробовал вставить для начала вывод монеток, что бы в будущем засунуть это значение в if, но при попытке вывода мне пришло вот это:

А вот код(уже модифицированный и дающий ошибку):

```
 con = sqlite3.connect('accs.db')

cur = con.cursor()

id1 = p1
id2 = p2
pay = p3
#sql = """SELECT coins FROM persons WHERE id=?"""   вот тут пытался получить монетки
# print(cur.execute(sql, [(id1)])) А вот это мне и выдало ошибку
sql = """
UPDATE persons 
SET coins = coins - ?   
WHERE id =?
```

Вот ошибка:  `<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x04B7AF20>`

Comment: Во-первых, это не ошибка. Метод `execute` возвращает курсор, текстовое представление которого выглядит как `<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x04B7AF20>`. Чтобы извлечь результаты запроса из курсора, используйте [fetchone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) или `fetchall`. Во-вторых, почитайте про транзакции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большое спасибо   [Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev) за помощь, вот так вышло:

```
sql = """SELECT coins FROM persons WHERE id=?"""  
cur.execute(sql, [(id1)])
if cur.fetchone()[0] < abs(int(pay)):         # abs - на случай если напишут отрицательное число, int - для того, что бы превратить цифру текстовую в цифру настоящую
    print('У вас не хватает денег')
 else:   #Выполняем нужный код
```